# React: Rendering two elements in the same frame

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a code, like

```
<Box>
 <SomeIcon/>
 <HightlightSearch query={query}>
   {text}
 </HightlightSearch>
</Box>
```

HighlightSearch uses innerHtlm to highlight query results in a child (text) - it is a pretty simple function that uses useEffect() inside with dependencies being child (text) and query.

What happens is that SomeIcon gets rendered first, and then, after a very short but noticeable time, the text gets rendered (I can clearly see it if I use per-frame view of React devtools in Chrome).

When I remove HightlightSearch, the issue goes away

Is there a way for me to make sure the icon and the text are rendered together?

Comment: Look up `useLayoutEffect`. It executes its callback and rerenders the component immediately instead of on the next frame like `useEffect`

Comment: Thank you - seems to work! If you could make it a reply, I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`. It executes its callback and rerenders the component immediately instead of on the next frame.